# Fast way to do big directory listings

Tags: c++, filesystems

I want to know how a fast directory listing can be obtained, of e.g. a whole hard disk drive.

In C++ I have been using `dirent.h` with a recursive directory listing. This works nice of course, but the more you're listing, the longer it takes and a 500GB drive would easily take an hour to be scanned.
This has to do with the fragmentation, while one file or directory could be at the outer part of the disk, the next one could be at the innermost. Worst case would be a jump from innermost part to outermost part on every read access.
Of course the hard disk will always be a bottleneck, but I used applications that delivered a directory listing of the drive in about 2-5 minutes.
How did they do it?
Some sources on google said something about accessing the "Master File Table" of the file system.
Alright, but how would I do that and what about NTFS, FAT, Ext4, they are certainly using different styles of tables, aren't they?

Well, this is a very broad question, I know, so for the sake of clarification I narrow it down to this:
Could someone please explain what these "Master File Tables" are and how the mentioned file systems use them.
Is using these tables the right approach to this task?
How would I access such a table in C++, they sure have no path like `/root/.filesystem/master_file_table`.
Any explanation, resource or push in the right direction is welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: You're making assumptions that it would "easily take an hour to be scanned".  Maybe your code is not efficient.

Comment: I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link referring to specific C++ code using the master file table for an NTFS drive with a brief forum [post](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?458574-Reading-in-the-Master-File-Table-%28MFT%29&s=b4276d4dcef3f6e03fcb73fedd86dcfb&p=1802906#post1802906) about finding/reading the MFT. The page I found that on is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: One thing that *can* help a great deal is to use a breadth-first search instead of the depth-first search you'll normally get from a recursive search. The basic idea is that when you get to a directory entry, instead of recursively searching it immediately, you put its path in a queue. When you finish the current directory, you get the next one from the queue (so you search *all* of one directory before looking at the next). I've seen this better than double the speed of traversing a large directory tree.

Comment: Thanks for your hint Mister, this indeed improved the time it takes. Although I hoped to learn some things about the file tables, but this should be sufficient. Thanks again!